# Is there a difference where to place super?

Tags: java, super

I wonder i placment a super in different possitions makes any difference to functionality.

```
public void test(){
super.test()
// my code
}
```

and

```
public void test(){
//my code
super.test()
}
```

Is it exactly the same?

Comment: It kindof depends on what `//my code` does, if it has any effects the parent class is aware of

Comment: Yes, interchanging statements changes the order they are executed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not the same. In the first example, the method of the super class is executed first while in your second example it's executed in last. This little example will demonstrate this :

Consider this :

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        new Child().test(5);
    }
}
class Parent {
    public void test(int a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    @Override
    public void test(int a){
        super.test(a);
        a++;
    }
}
```

It will print 5.

However if I place the super call at the end of the overriden test method,

```
class Child extends Parent{
    @Override
    public void test(int a){
        a++;
        super.test(a);
    }
}
```

it will print 6.

Answer (score 2):

If you call super class method `test()` before your code, the super class method will be called before your subclass method code named as `my code` executed. Order of execution will change according to your order which you have placed in the method.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. The code in your test() method is run sequentially.

Thus, calling

```
new B().test();
new C().test();
```

on

```
class A {
  public void test() {
     System.out.print("A");
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public void test() {
     System.out.println("B");
     super.test();
  }
}

class C extends A {
  public void test() {
     super.test();
     System.out.println("C");
  }
}
```

will result in the output:

```
BA
AC
```